# Is it safe to assume that a thread created from the main thread is running in the background?

Tags: android, multithreading

For an app I'm developing, I created a thread from the main thread as follows:

```
            Thread background = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Log.d ("Thread", "Thread has started");
                processImage(data, size.width, size.height, camera);
                camera.addCallbackBuffer(data);
                Log.d ("Thread", "Thread has ended");
                }
            });

            if (!background.isAlive){
                background.start();
            }
```

Now, is it safe to assume that this newly created thread is running along with the main thread (in the backgroud)?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, a "thread running in the foreground" is just defined as the main thread. Thus all other threads are effectively running in the background. Though another definition of background-thread is just a "thread that won't keep the application alive". I don't think this applies to android though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is safe, after you called start. You can always use the `isAlive()` method to check whether the thread is executing. Why would you need such an assumption, anyway?

Comment: What I want to do is, to get a frame from the camera and to process that frame and when this is happening, I want the main thread to continue getting the frames and to check if the thread is active; if the thread is active then I want the main thread to discard that frame and get a new frame and if it's not, then I want it to create a thread which processes that frame.

Answer (score 0):

I believe so, as the main thread is always thread id #1 (if you don't believe me, check `Thread.currentThread().getId()`), and gets initialized before your code does (in your particular case). once that main thread has been created, any subsequent `new Thread()` should trigger a new instance, which is never the main thread.